# 3D Lorenz Attractor animation

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

I've been trying to make an animation of the `Lorenz Attractor` being plotted using `matplotlib`. I already have a successful static plot and now I am trying to animate it. I have been going off the documentation for matplotlib animation to do so but, whenever I go to run my program I get an empty box no animation, I am also using `spyder ide's` plots but, I also ran it in a terminal.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

x_values = np.array([])
y_values = np.array([])
z_values = np.array([])

#^Lorenz Attractor coordinates size = 1000

fig = plt.figure(facecolor="black")
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
ln, = ax.plot([], [], [])

 #^Plot configuration.
```

Above is the where I make most of my variables. x-z_values is where the points for the `Lorenz Attractor` points are stored

```
def init():
    return ln,

#initializer for animation function


def update(i):
    ln.set_data(x_values[i], y_values[i], z_values[i])
    return ln,
#Adds next values of Lorenz Attractor to ln which will be returned to animation to be plotteed
    

Lorenz()
#Calls the Lorenz function to populate the arrays.

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, 
                    update,
                    frames = np.arange(0, len(x_values)), 
                    init_func = init,
                    interval=200,
                    )
plt.show()
```

This is where the animation is supposed to take place.

[image]

And this is what I get after running the program.

### **Update**:

I've changed some code I am no longer using ln to collect the coordinate values, so the line below for example has been removed
`ln.set_data(x_values[i], y_values[i], z_values[i])`

Below is the new code including the new update function that uses the values from a separate function named `Lorenz()`, the variables which are globally available. The `print()` debugging suggested by Furas has validated that `update()` is working as expected. The only problem left to solve is the actual animation.

`

```
def init():
    ax.set_xlim(-100, 100)
    ax.set_ylim(-100, 100)
    ax.set_zlim(-100, 100)

#initializer for animation function


def update(i):
    global x_values 
    global y_values
    global z_values
    #Globally available variables that are poulated by Lorenz()
    print(x_values[i], y_values[i], z_values[i])
    #Print debugging
    return(x_values[:i], y_values[:i], z_values[:i])

#Adds next values of Lorenz Attractor to ln which will be returned to animation to be plotteed
Lorenz()
ani = FuncAnimation(fig, 
                    update,
                    frames = np.arange(0, len(x_values)), 
                    init_func=init,
                    interval=1,
                    blit=False,
                    repeat = False)

plt.show()
```

`

Comment: What if you do `[:i]` for your indexing in `set_data`?

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: @jared Just tried that and it didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @furas after putting a print line in my update function it does not seem like the update function is being called because I am not getting anything in the terminal.

Comment: maybe check also `print( len(x_values) )` because you have `frames = np.arange(0, len(x_values))` and if `len(x_values))` gives `0` then there is nothing to `update`.

Comment: I would create arrays in function and do `x_values, y_values, z_values = Lorenz()`. It better shows how you get these values.

Comment: @furas Just fixed some issues with the x_values not being updated globally. This seems to fix the issue with the update function not being called. But I am still not getting points plotted.

Comment: I have no idea. First I would use `print()` in `update()` to see if it is executed and what values it sets. And as @jared suggested you may need `[:i]` to add new pixel to plot because using `[i]` you display only one pixel in every frame of animation and you may not see it.

Comment: @user297763 Update the post with the new code. And yes, you'll need to do `[:i]` because you want all the points up to `i` to be shown, not just the `i`th point.

Comment: @furas Yes, update is performing as expected. After adding ``[:i]`` I have still not seen any plotting yet. Also thank you for all your help I am really grateful.

Comment: @jared Got it will update now. I also have not seen any animation still after adding `[:i]`

Comment: @user297763 You don't return those values, you should update the line like you were doing before.

Comment: `update()` needs `[:i]` or `[0:i]` like `ln.set_data(x_values[0:i], y_values[0:i], z_values[0:i])` and always `return ln,`

Comment: @furas I am getting errors when i try to set 3 values to ln.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never made animation for `3D`
but based on example [Animated 3D random walk](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/animation/random_walk.html#sphx-glr-gallery-animation-random-walk-py)  in `Matplotlib` documentation you need:

```
def update(i):
    ln.set_data( [x_values[:i], y_values[:i]] )   # set [x, y]
    ln.set_3d_properties( z_values[:i] )          # set z
    return ln,
```

---

Full working code with example data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import numpy as np 

# --- functions ---

def Lorenz():
    x = np.zeros(100)
    y = np.zeros(100)
    z = np.zeros(100)

    for i in range(100):
        x[i] = i/100
        y[i] = i/100
        z[i] = i/100
        
    return x, y, z

def init():
    return ln,

def update(i):
    ln.set_data([ x_values[:i], y_values[:i]])
    ln.set_3d_properties( z_values[:i] )
    return ln,
    
# --- main ---

fig = plt.figure(facecolor="black")
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
ln, = ax.plot([], [], [])

x_values, y_values, z_values = Lorenz()

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, 
                    update,
                    frames=len(x_values),  # you don't need range (if you don't want to skip some frames)
                    init_func=init,
                    interval=20,  # make animation faster 
                    )
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry for not responding sooner I had not seen your answer. It looks like we came to our answers at the same time. Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to use `FuncAnimation()` for a 3D plot you would have to use a list variable that is set equal to a plot like:  `lines, = ax.plot([], [], [])` in your `update()` function. You would then use `.set_data()` on `line,`  to first set the x and y values then you would use `.set_3d_properties()` to set the z values. The code would look like what is shown below.

```
def init():
    a=30
    ax.set_xlim(-a, a)
    ax.set_ylim(-a, a)
    ax.set_zlim(-a, a)

#initializer for animation function

def update(i):
    global x_values 
    global y_values
    global z_values
    #Globally available variables that are populated by Lorenz()
    
    print(x_values[i], y_values[i], z_values[i])
    #Prints out the current position of particle on screen
    lines.set_data(x_values[0:i], y_values[0:i])
    lines.set_3d_properties(z_values[0:i])
    
    return lines

#Adds next values of Lorenz Attractor to ln which will be returned to animation to be plotteed

lines, = ax.plot([], [], [])

Lorenz()
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, 
                    update,
                    frames = np.arange(0, len(x_values)), 
                    init_func=init,
                    interval=1,
                    blit=False,
                    repeat = 'False'
                    )
#ani.save('Lorenz1.gif', writer='imagemagick')


plt.show()
```

This produced the following:
[image]